# Creating a Git repro on my website

Tags: git, init

I'm not clear on which folder I should CD into to create my Git init?

My Linux server folder structure is home/account/public_html

Should I be in my public_html folder when I do the init?

Thanks...

Comment: Mine aren't in public folders, they're in other ones. That's mostly preference.

Comment: I plan to 'pushing' my website php files up into the public_html folder...so I'm wondering for that to work if I need to git init in that folder or if I can git init in any folder I want? I guess I'm not clear on how git knows what folder to push into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have mine structured where the git repo is in my private area (not visible to the web, technically) and setup a `post-receive` hook to publish the changes to the site.

The only major downside I can think of is that you cannot `http` checkout and that *some hosts* block the port that git uses.

You can set up a post-receive hook in a repo with:

1. `cd` to your `git repo`
2. Create the `post-receive` hook file (`hooks/post-receive`) with the following content and make it executable.

   `#!/usr/bin/env bash`
   `GIT_WORK_TREE=/path/to/site/folder`
3. `chmod +x hooks/post-receive`

Now when you push changes, it'll checkout to your site directory (i.e. publish your changes).

[[Source](http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto)]

Comment: I'm new to Git but I was just thinking, maybe I don't need to create a Git repro on my website? I'm only going to be pushing my local PC files to the website (in the public_html folder) so why would I need a Git repro on the site? My local machine I understand I need a Git repro so I can manage my branches, etc. locally. But if I'm just pushing to my site, why would I need a Git repro there?

Comment: That's a design question you should answer.  I'm speaking directly to your OP asking which folder on the webserver you should use.  I expanded on it to automatically publish your changes for you.  The pluses of it being on the server are multiple points of backup (i.e. you have a copy locally and the master on the server.  It's unlikely *both* would go down at the same time.  However, it is likely one will fail at some point.). In any case, I would use the hook to automatically publish it for me.  You could have two repos, one local and one remote.  Doesn't really matter.